# Postgres selection with dynamic column name

Tags: postgresql, select, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to query a table with a lot of columns like debMonth1, debMonth2 etc. to get a result that fits the needs for the application that needs to process the data.

Syntactically the query seems to be OK now, but I don't get a result from it. It just proceeds with no error.

I think I got problems regarding the column names? Can anybody help me out?

```
DO $do$
DECLARE cmonth TEXT;
DECLARE dmonth TEXT;

BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..15 LOOP

cmonth = CONCAT('"credMonth' , i::text, '"');   
dmonth = CONCAT('"debMonth' , i::text, '"');

EXECUTE
format('SELECT 
    "account", "FY", "setOfBooks", $1, $2, $3 AS "fiscalMonth"
FROM 
    "transaction_figures" 
WHERE 
    "dataType" = ''(80)'' AND 
    ($1 != ''0.00'' OR $2 != ''0.00'')')
USING cmonth, dmonth, i;

END LOOP;
END
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries executed in plpgsql don't result in printing its output nor sending to client. You have to iterate over the results and do something with it, for example:

```
DO $do$
DECLARE cmonth TEXT;
DECLARE dmonth TEXT;
DECLARE r RECORD;

BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..15 LOOP

cmonth = CONCAT('"credMonth' , i::text, '"');   
dmonth = CONCAT('"debMonth' , i::text, '"');

FOR r in
    EXECUTE
    format('SELECT 
        "account", "FY", "setOfBooks", $1, $2, $3 AS "fiscalMonth"
    FROM 
        "transaction_figures" 
    WHERE 
        "dataType" = ''(80)'' AND 
        ($1 != ''0.00'' OR $2 != ''0.00'')')
    USING cmonth, dmonth, i
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', r;
END LOOP;

END LOOP;
END
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This will print results in psql. If you would like to have data behaving like table (i.e. sent to client) you have to wrap your code in plpgsql function and return query result.